# My CPT has archive false, now I need use parent Page for slug

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type 'services', but the archive is false, I am using a page as services.

But now I need this slug

mydomain.com/services/taxonomy/post2

How I can link my taxonomies with Services page as parent.

It is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your register_taxonomy $args list, you need to add this:

```
"rewrite" => array( "slug" => "services/taxonomy", "with_front" => true ),
```

This will prepend services to your taxonomy slug.

See here for more arguments: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If it answered your question make sure you make it as solved!

Comment: Be aware that this could break pagination for the listing page.